# How can i build a executable jar from a netbeans opencv project which has native library dependencies?

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

I could run an opencv project(windows) in netbeans using 'run' button.But i want to make it as an executable jar.Is it possible? How can i do it ?The problem is that it is linked with a dll.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `java -jar test.jar`

and add below sample in run

`-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Desktop\opencv\build\java\x64"`

(http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/717283/How-to-Use-OpenCV-with-Java-under-NetBeans-IDE)

Comment: this will not describe the answer